# random string (variable) generator based on user input

Tags: linux, bash, docker, random

i need to get a script, which will ask user to input a number (from 1 to ....... lets say 100, does not matter), and then based on number entered generate n random strings (aplphanumeric nevermind), which can be used as variables.
an example, as im not sure i made it clear:
user is asked to choose a number, he chooses 6 (for example).
6 random strings are generated (for example:
dq3rqewfdwq3
aefr3wqf3fd3
d2dqdq32re3q
32d3dq3fef33
3r243fr4wef4
r23r23r32r3r, and then they are used one by one as variables (dockerfile container names) in running docker
so in this case:
docker run --name dq3rqewfdwq3 ......
docker run --name aefr3wqf3fd3 ......
and so on.......
so it runs as many times as user input number.
really appriciate help with this

Comment: Are you asking how to do a loop? Are you asking how to generate a random string?

Comment: why?  `docker run` already generates a random name for a container if `--name` isn't used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pwgen` an `xargs`, and using a number that is given as a command line argument for the number of repetitions:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

pwgen -A 16 "$1" | xargs -I {} docker run --name {} other options here
```

This would be used like

```bash
./thescript 6
```

... and it would use `pwgen` to generate the given number of random strings, each 16 characters long. For each generated string, `xargs` would run `docker` with the string inserted in the place of the `{}` placeholder.

The `-A` option to `pwgen` causes it only to create strings without uppercase letters.

If invoked as shown above, this may, for example, run the commands

```bash
docker run --name iepiephei8va1oas other options here
docker run --name eihengugeang8op9 other options here
docker run --name teithosho7ez8pho other options here
docker run --name jugh6eem7fae0hah other options here
docker run --name chak9nooxahxohl4 other options here
docker run --name iewuph1aemohwoza other options here
```

Comment: thank you so much. works as expected :)